# Excel recognizes workSheet.Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex) as Range

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to color excel cells based on Male/Female genre. I was comparing the cell value to know which style i have to apply when Excel thrown this exception:

> The "Values" member could not be found in the "Range" type

on this line: `If wSheet.Cells(rowIndex, MFindex).Values = "MALE" Then`

**This is what I've tried:**

```
For Each dr In dt.Rows
            rowIndex += 1
            If wSheet.Cells(rowIndex, mfIndex).Values = "MALE" Then
                wSheet.Range(range).Style = "Male"
            ElseIf wSheet.Cells(rowIndex, mfIndex).Values = "FEMALE" Then
                wSheet.Range(range).Style = "Female"
            End If
Next
```

A few lines earlier I did this and it works fine:

```
If wSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Value = wSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, 1).Value Then
```

Var `range` contains the range of the line (it's a simplification, don't ask about it. It has nothing to do with the exception.)

I also tell you that `mfIndex` is the column index of Male/Female cells

I created my Excel sheet from my `dt as DataTable` so they have the same number of rows and columns.

I checked `rowIndex` and `mfIndex` and their values are `rowIndex = 1`, `mfIndex = 26`

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and working on an `.xlsx` file

**Why is Excel throwing an exception? What did I do wrong?**

Comment: It's `Value` not `Values`.

Comment: Oh my god... Thanks!! Next time better use autocompiler...

If you post your comment as an answer I will be glad to flag it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
If wSheet.Cells(rowIndex, MFindex).Value = "MALE" Then
```

Note that it is `Value` and not `Values`. :)